# XSLT and XPATH to find the correct element using data from sibling elements

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm having trouble locating the correct syntax for finding the value of an element based on sibling element data.

Given that I have the following XML:

```
<files>
    <file>
        <location>location1.txt</location>
        <metadata>
            <foo>some value 1</foo>
        </metadata>
    </file>
    <file>
        <location>location2.txt</location>
        <metadata>
            <foo>some value 2</foo>
        </metadata>
    </file>
    <file>
        <location>location3.txt</location>
        <metadata />
    </file>
</files>
```

What is the correct XPATH expression to find the correct location value if I'm looking for only the location where file/metadata/foo = "some value 2"?  I can't seem to find the right syntax to locate it if I'm dependent on data in a sibling, or the children of that sibling.

I've found a solution where I use xslt to iterate through the file elements, and find the appropriate value that way, but it's not very elegant.

```
<xsl:variable name="profileAlias">
    <xsl:for-each select="files/file">
        <xsl:if test="metadata/foo='some value 2'">
            <xsl:value-of select="location">
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take one only value you can try this one, if this is elegent for you :D

```
<xsl:value-of select="files/file/location[following-sibling::metadata/foo/text()='some value 2']"/>
```

files/file/location - takes location attribute

[following-sibling::metadata/foo/ - which has next attribute metadata/foo/

text()='some value 2'] - with text equal 'some value 2'

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/files/file[metadata/foo='some value 2']/location
```